# Play a video Url in a qwidget Qt

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

I Am a beginner in Qt learning so forgive me if this question is already asked but believe me, i searched but i didn't find anything just like what I want.
So  I want to play an Url video using `QMediaPlayer` and `QVideoWidget`, when i did try this code:

```
//remplir playlist
playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Wafae/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/maFenetre/relax-3-minutes-rainforest-animals-waterfall-and-rain-sounds.mp4"));
playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Wafae/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/maFenetre/3-minutes-that-will-change-your-life-beautiful-nature-relaxing-inspiring-video.mp4"));

-------------
--------------
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("https://youtu.be/6v2L2UGZJAM"));
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);

    //player code
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->setVolume(100);

    //positionner videowidget
    videoWidget->setGeometry(100,100,500,400);
    videoWidget->show();
    myLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
    myLayout->addWidget(videoWidget);
       -------
     --------
---------
player->play();
```

but it skip it and come back to the first local video

Can any one help me please!

Comment: The URL that isn't playing appears to be an HTML web page.  I don't think that's ever been a supported \`format'.

Comment: I agree but i am searching for a solution anyway thanks